# Android: Play music from widget without starting app

Tags: android

In Google Play app if the app is not running and you click play from the widget, it start the song and notification appears but the app is not started. How do I achieve the same? How can I play song from widget without starting app?

Answer (score 0):

You should play music using a service.
Take a look at a project  https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer

Read about services and receivers.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html